# Error too many arguments to function

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I'm continuing to get this error, I've looked over my code multiple times and I can't see where I've taken a wrong turn. The program is supposed to have 5 users input a rating and then it finds the highest and lowest inputs, returning them to the user along with the average.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream> // whatever this is
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int getValue();
int findLowest();
int findHighest();
double findAverage();

int main(){  // main function

    cout << setw(15)<<""<< "Product Review"; // displays this at the top

    int ratingOne = getValue();
    int ratingTwo = getValue();
    int ratingThree = getValue();
    int ratingFour = getValue();
    int ratingFive = getValue();
    int low = findLowest(ratingOne, ratingTwo, ratingThree, ratingFour, ratingFive);
    int high = findHighest(ratingOne, ratingTwo, ratingThree, ratingFour, ratingFive);
    double average = findAverage(ratingOne, ratingTwo, ratingThree, ratingFour, ratingFive);

    cout << "\nThe highest rating received was: " << high;
    cout << "\nThe lowest rating received was: " << low;
    cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "\nThe average rating received among 5 users was: " << average;
}

int getValue(){
    int rating; 

    do {
        cout << "\nOn a scale of 1 to 10, how would you rate our product? ";
        cin >> rating; 

        if (rating < 1 || rating > 10) {cout << "\nYou have entered an invalid number. Please try again.";}
    } while (rating < 1 || rating > 10);
    return rating;
}

int findLowest(){
    int low = 11;
    if (ratingOne < low) { low = ratingOne }
    if (ratingTwo < low) { low = ratingTwo }
    if (ratingThree < low) { low = ratingThree }
    if (ratingFour < low) { low = ratingFour }
    if (ratingFive < low) { low = ratingFive }
    return low;
}
int findHighest(){
    int high = 0;
    if (ratingOne > high) { high = ratingOne }
    if (ratingTwo > high) { high = ratingTwo }
    if (ratingThree > high) { high = ratingThree }
    if (ratingFour > high) { high = ratingFour }
    if (ratingFive > high) { high = ratingFive }
    return high;
}
double findAverage(){
    double average;
    average = ratingOne + ratingTwo + ratingThree + ratingFour + ratingFive;
    average = average / 5;
    return average;
}
```

Comment: `findlowest()` doesn't take any parameters, you'recalling it with 5 arguments. The same with `findHighest` and `findAverage`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Make `ratingOne`, `ratingTwo`, `ratingThree`, `ratingFour` and `ratingOne` global and call the three functions `findLowest`, `findHighest` and `findAverage` without any parameter in the `main`. Or change the function signature to accept five `int`.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not 100% familiar with the terminology. I thought that calling the function would just utilize the variables stored within the (). We're not allowed to use global variables.

Comment: @jm21609 No, that's not how function calling works. You need to reread the section on calling functions in your textbook or tutorial.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS I should have mentioned that we're not allowed to use global variables in our code. How would I change the signature to accept 5 integers?

Comment: You can use variadic templates and SFINAE :)

Comment: Well then you can change you function definition to the one mentioned in the answers

Comment: @Barmar This is a "Z" course, so we're not given a textbook. The tutorials are extremely simple and just give examples for the most basic calling of functions (i.e calling "first()" to display a cout statement)

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS -- making those variables global is a really bad idea.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS I tried Sebi's code example and it returns an error saying that "ratingOne" et al was not declared in this scope

Comment: @jm21609 -- You're lucky you only have 5 ratings, and even so you should really start using arrays.  What if there were 100 such ratings?  Write 100 `if` statements or have the average computed with an endless number of `+` signs?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie we're not allowed to use arrays, probably due to the fact that we haven't covered them yet. I'm familiar with arrays but I understand what you're saying for sure

Comment: @jm21609 Don't take the downvotes personally. It's very common for people to downvote questions that indicates a total lack of understanding of the language. You're expected to know the basics.

Comment: @Barmar Everyone's gotta start somewhere, right?

Comment: Sure, but they don't have to post to Stack Overflow while they're doing it. This site isn't supposed to be a programming school.

Comment: @Barmar I thought this site was a community of programmers of all skill levels. It seems like there's plenty of resources and questions littered all over the place, I just searched on google and found it. If it's for more advanced programmers, I'll seek assistance elsewhere as to not waste people's time with simple questions

Comment: You don't have to be an advanced programmer, but you should be a programmer. It's not the place to learn the fundamentals.

Comment: @jm21609 *we're not allowed to use arrays, probably due to the fact that we haven't covered them yet* -- There is no indication that you are restricted in what you can use.   A lot of questions posted here start out with bad C++ implementations, with the answers given showing techniques the poster has never seen before that are much shorter.  The poster is glad and gives the person answering the question the green check mark.  How do we know you were not one of these persons?  Next time indicate what you're restricted in using.

Answer (score 1):

The number of, and type of parameters in your function prototype

```
int findLowest();
int findHighest();
double findAverage();
```

should match those in your definitions. They don't. It appears you want to pass arguments (5) of type `int` to the functions above hence in the prototype. You'll have to specify that.

```
int findLowest(int, int, int, int, int);
int findHighest(int, int, int, int, int);
double findAverage(int, int, int, int, int);
```

Also, in your functions definition.

```
int findLowest(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree,  int ratingFour, int ratingFive){...}
int findHighest(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree,  int ratingFour, int ratingFive){...}
double findAverage(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree,  int ratingFour, int ratingFive){..}
```

and the number of arguments and types when calling the functions should also match your function definition.

Comment: I changed my prototypes to 
    int findLowest(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree, int ratingFour, int ratingFive);

Comment: The program is just now giving me an error stating "undefined reference to 'findlowest(int, int, int, int, int)'

Comment: @ jm21 its OK. stating the identifier for a parameter in  prototype is for readability which is encourage. but in small program just the type of the parameters is enough.

Comment: @jm21 check the name of function findlowest in definition does not match that in prototype.

Comment: I'm totally lost. I've checked all three of them. They're all the same, no capitalization errors, they're all declared as int, I'm really not sure what else it could be

Answer (score 0):

The functions findLowest and findHighest don't have any parameters but you have provided 5. To do it correctly you should write:

```
#include <iostream> // whatever this is
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int getValue();
int findLowest(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree, int ratingFour, int ratingFive);
int findHighest(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree, int ratingFour, int ratingFive);
double findAverage(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree, int ratingFour, int ratingFive);


int main(){  // main function

cout << setw(15)<<""<< "Product Review"; // displays this at the top    

int ratingOne = getValue();
int ratingTwo = getValue();
int ratingThree = getValue();
int ratingFour = getValue();
int ratingFive = getValue();
int low = findLowest(ratingOne, ratingTwo, ratingThree, ratingFour, ratingFive);
int high = findHighest(ratingOne, ratingTwo, ratingThree, ratingFour, ratingFive);
double average = findAverage(ratingOne, ratingTwo, ratingThree, ratingFour, ratingFive);

cout << "\nThe highest rating received was: " << high;
cout << "\nThe lowest rating received was: " << low;
cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "\nThe average rating received among 5 users was: " << average;
}

int getValue(){
int rating; 

do {
cout << "\nOn a scale of 1 to 10, how would you rate our product? ";
cin >> rating; 

if (rating < 1 || rating > 10) {cout << "\nYou have entered an invalid number. Please try again.";}
} 

while (rating < 1 || rating > 10);
return rating;
}

int findLowest(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree, int ratingFour, int ratingFive){
int low = 11;
if (ratingOne < low) { low = ratingOne; }
if (ratingTwo < low) { low = ratingTwo; }
if (ratingThree < low) { low = ratingThree; }
if (ratingFour < low) { low = ratingFour; }
if (ratingFive < low) { low = ratingFive; }
return low;
}
int findHighest(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree, int ratingFour, int ratingFive){
int high = 0;
if (ratingOne > high) { high = ratingOne; }
if (ratingTwo > high) { high = ratingTwo; }
if (ratingThree > high) { high = ratingThree; }
if (ratingFour > high) { high = ratingFour; }
if (ratingFive > high) { high = ratingFive; }
return high;
}
double findAverage(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree, int ratingFour, int ratingFive){
double average;
average = ratingOne + ratingTwo + ratingThree + ratingFour + ratingFive;
average = average / 5;
return average;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I was just missing the "int" in front of each individual declaration. Do I need to declare everything inside the functions as well? I'm now just getting an error stating "ratingOne" etc was not declared in this scope

Comment: I declared "int ratingOne;" etc in each function, and that error went away. Now the last remaining issue is: "undefined reference to 'findlowest(int, int, int, int, int)' for all three functions

Comment: sorry...should really compile before i post. Won't happen again :)

Comment: and yeah I saw that, I added those as well earlier, just forgot to paste it in the original post :p

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out, but I don't know WHY. This is my final code.

```
#include <iostream> // whatever this is
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int getValue();
int findLowest(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree, int ratingFour, int ratingFive);
int findHighest(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree, int ratingFour, int ratingFive);
double findAverage(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree, int ratingFour, int ratingFive);


int main(){  // main function

cout << setw(15)<<""<< "Product Review"; // displays this at the top

int ratingOne = getValue();
int ratingTwo = getValue();
int ratingThree = getValue();
int ratingFour = getValue();
int ratingFive = getValue();
int low = findLowest(ratingOne, ratingTwo, ratingThree, ratingFour, ratingFive);
int high = findHighest(ratingOne, ratingTwo, ratingThree, ratingFour, ratingFive);
double average = findAverage(ratingOne, ratingTwo, ratingThree, ratingFour, ratingFive);

cout << "\nThe highest rating received was: " << high;
cout << "\nThe lowest rating received was: " << low;
cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "\nThe average rating received among 5 users was: " << average;
}

int getValue(){
int rating; 

do {
cout << "\nOn a scale of 1 to 10, how would you rate our product? ";
cin >> rating; 

    if (rating < 1 || rating > 10) {cout << "\nYou have entered an invalid number. Please try again.";}
}

while (rating < 1 || rating > 10);
return rating;
}

int findLowest(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree, int ratingFour, int ratingFive){
int low = 11;
if (ratingOne < low) { low = ratingOne; }
if (ratingTwo < low) { low = ratingTwo; }
if (ratingThree < low) { low = ratingThree; }
if (ratingFour < low) { low = ratingFour; }
if (ratingFive < low) { low = ratingFive;}
return low;
}
int findHighest(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree, int ratingFour, int ratingFive){
int high = 0;
if (ratingOne > high) { high = ratingOne; }
if (ratingTwo > high) { high = ratingTwo; }
if (ratingThree > high) { high = ratingThree; }
if (ratingFour > high) { high = ratingFour; }
if (ratingFive > high) { high = ratingFive; }
return high;
}
double findAverage(int ratingOne, int ratingTwo, int ratingThree, int ratingFour, int ratingFive){
double average;
average = ratingOne + ratingTwo + ratingThree + ratingFour + ratingFive;
average = average / 5;
return average;
}
```

I had this as my code before, and it gave me the errors I discussed above.
    int findLowest(){...}

I also got the program to compile by just saying "int" 5 times in the (), but the values were astronomically out of whack. I'd input the 5 numbers 1-10 and the results were something like 24908140489, -301213901398, 489723498234 or whatever. Not sure why that happened, but maybe it was the default value for a stored number and something was wrong. Should have saved that edit to look back on it, because now I don't know what caused it to happen. At least it works now, thanks for the assistance!